# pop() implementation - array based stack

Tags: java, arrays, stack

Currently wrestling with a homework assignment where we are required to implement an array-based implementation of the stack. I am struggling with the pop() method. See below for my current implementation:

```
public Object pop() throws EmptyStackException {
    if (isEmpty())
      throw new EmptyStackException();

    this.size--;
    Object result = this.elements[size];
    this.elements[size] = null;

    if (size < (capacity / 4)) {
      capacity = capacity / 2;
      Object temp[] = elements;
      elements = new Object[capacity];

      for (int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++)
        elements[i] = temp[i];
    }
    return result;
}
```

The issue I am having is that in its current iteration, the pop method does not remove items from the array, and does not decrease the list capacity at the specified level, that is when size is less than 25% of capacity.

Comment: You shouldn't need to resize on a pop as you can leave it the size that it was.

Comment: It looks like it removes an element for the array to me.  Try getting this to work without the resize first.

Comment: What do you mean by does not remove items? If you look up in this.elements[size] after the method you'll find an obj and not null?

Comment: In the for loop, the upper bound should be elements.length, otherwise it will trigger an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException. Otherwise it looks fine to me. I agree with Peter that you should first fix the first issue before optimizing capacity.

Comment: Upper bound should be the size, not the length. Why copy all the nulls? I agree with @Peter Lawrey that resizing downward is usually unnecessary.

Comment: @all, one of the specifications is that the array is resized when size is less than 25% of capacity.

Comment: Can you update the question adding the init phase and the push function?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick & dirty (and "easy" for a student):

```
public class MyStack
{

    Object[] elements;
    int size;
    int capacity;

    public MyStack()
    {
        this.capacity = 1;
        this.elements = new Object[capacity];
        this.size = 0;

    }

    public boolean isEmpty()
    {
        return (size == 0);
    }

    public void push(Object obj)
    {
        if (size == capacity) {
            capacity = capacity * 2;
            resize();
        }
        elements[size] = obj;
        size++;
    }

    public Object pop() throws Exception
    {
        if (isEmpty()) {
            throw new Exception();
        }

        this.size--;
        Object result = this.elements[size];
        this.elements[size] = null;

        if (size < (capacity / 4)) {
            capacity = capacity / 2;
            resize();
        }
        return result;
    }

    private void resize()
    {
        Object temp[] = elements;
        elements = new Object[capacity];

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
            elements[i] = temp[i];
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        MyStack my = new MyStack();
        my.push(1);
        my.push(2);
        my.push(3);
        my.push(4);
        my.push(5);

        Object o5 = my.pop();
        Object o4 = my.pop();
        Object o3 = my.pop();
        Object o2 = my.pop();
        Object o1 = my.pop();
        Object o0 = null;
        try {
            o0 = my.pop();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Empty stack");
        }
        System.out.println(String.format("%s %s %s %s %s %s", o5, o4, o3, o2, o1, o0));

    }
}
```